# How do I install 32-bit perl-tgicl 2.1.1?

Tags: package-management, synaptic, 32-bit

I'm trying to install a .deb and I need some packages but they are not on the synaptic.

How can I install this packages

lib32z1

libc6-i386

```
TGICL$ sudo dpkg -i perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all.deb 
Selecting previously deselected package perl-tgicl.
(Reading database ... 168515 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking perl-tgicl (from perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all.deb) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of perl-tgicl:
 perl-tgicl depends on lib32z1 (>= 1:1.1.4); however:
  Package lib32z1 is not installed.
 perl-tgicl depends on libc6-i386 (>= 2.3); however:
  Package libc6-i386 is not installed.
 perl-tgicl depends on libfile-homedir-perl (>= 0.10); however:
  Package libfile-homedir-perl is not installed.
 perl-tgicl depends on libfile-spec-perl (>= 0.10); however:
  Package libfile-spec-perl is not installed.
dpkg: error processing perl-tgicl (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 perl-tgicl
```

My OS:

```
$ uname -a
Linux 3.0.0-12-generic-pae #20-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 7 16:37:17 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: They seem to be in the Main repository, so you should be able to install them either with Software Center or with apt-get.

Answer (score 1):

Actually all of the missing packages are in repositories. dpkg can not handle dependencies itself. You must provide them. Use that command:

> sudo apt-get -f install

So all the dependencies will be installed alongside with perl-tgicl.

---

Those packages are not suitable for an i386 system I think. So we'll follow [this thread](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15660).
First, install those two packages:

> sudo apt-get install libfile-homedir-perl libfile-spec-perl

After installing those just extract the perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all.deb package to you home directory. You can do this by moving the .deb file to your home directory and right click->Extract here. You should have a directory named **perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all** now.

Drop that directory via:

> cd ~/perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all

and copy the executables to /usr/local/bin

> sudo cp usr/bin/* /usr/local/bin

Copy the config file to /etc

> sudo cp etc/tgicl.cfg /etc

Set the perl5 libs:

> export PERL5LIB=/**your_home_directory_path**/perl-tgicl_2.1-1_all/usr/share/perl5:$PERL5LIB

Change here the bolded part. ie, if your user name is daniel use /home/daniel.

Note: If you have perl5 installed I think /usr/share/perl5 path works here either.

I achieved to run the tgicl but there must be an input file I think to try it. If you have one (I think you have) just comment out DB_FILE line in the config file that you copied in /etc. Then use your input file from command line.

Comment: I wrote that but all executables and scripts from the program disappears, this remove the perl-tgicl package.

Comment: How did it remove perl-tgicl? It is not installed yet. You can try to install the needed packages one by one and after that install perl-tgicl. But this could be a dependency version problem. Where did you get perl-tgicl and is it compatible with 11.10?

Comment: Here is the link [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tgicl/) well first I wrote (sudo dpkg -i ....dev) then (sudo apt-get -f install) and in the terminal appears (The following packages will be REMOVED: perl-tgicl). I used apt-cache search to find lib32z1 and libc6-i386, but I didn't find any similar.

Comment: Ok, I updated my question. I think that package is not suitable for i386 systems. First two dependencies are for amd64 but package says all_deb.

Comment: I post that [thread](http://seqanswers.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15660), is other method and the result is the same, in both case I don't have the lib32z1 and libc6-i386 packages and the result is the same, so why in the terminal ask me about these packages? I'm confused.

Comment: Oh, I did not look the name :) So, I told you a solution, looking by your solution :) Those packages for 64bit systems, so actually we don't need them I think (also we dont have them in our (32bit) repositories). There could be some packaging issues maybe.